# Spring boot handle request in different controller differentiate by incoming domain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Existing `@RequestMapping` annotation can only delegate request path to different controllers & methods but not checking request domain itself.

Is it possible to set spring boot to handle request from "www.domainA.com" & "www.domainB.com" to respond differently by using the different controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers send the Domain in the HTTP Header "Host".

@RequestMapping.headers can be used to match only requests for a specific domain.